# resque job ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Could not find table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, resque

I have a resque-scheduler delayed job that is queued properly. **Everything is working nice an smootly on dev machine**. Once deployed the job get executed but failed. resque-web shows on the failed job tab the following error:

```
Exception: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid

Error: Could not find table 'articles'
```

The table articles exists, as I'm accessing it through the app.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initially was starting the appropriate resque tasks manually on the server and got the error. I changed the deployment strategy and ended up adding the resque task in the capistrano recipe...and it worked !!! another mystery solved. I guess the explanation is a mix of not being in the same rails context and user privileges.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the RAILS_ENV environment variable and Resque tries to use development database (which is not existing). This should work if you run the rake from the command line:

```
RAILS_ENV=production QUEUE=* rake resque:work
```